# filtering month in date angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I 've successed to filter a date with angularjs. but I want to filter the month only. i want if I typed `01` only titanic appears. here is my sample data.

**view**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" />
<tr ng-repeat="n in eventlist | filter:search">
    <td>{{n.name}}</td>
    <td>{{n.date | date:"dd MMMM yyyy"}}</td>
</tr>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.eventlist = [
    {name:"Titanic", date:"2016-01-24"},
    {name:"Civil War", date:"2016-07-01"}
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use custome filter for this. try like this.

```js
var app = angular.module('main', []);
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope,$filter) {

   $scope.eventlist =
     [
       {name:"Titanic", date:"2016-01-24"},
       {name:"Civil War", date:"2016-02-15"}
    ];
  
   $scope.myFilter = function(month,search){
       return function(event) {
          return event.date.split('-')[1] == $scope.search ?true:false;
         }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" ng-app="main">
   <input type="text" ng-model="search" />
   <div ng-repeat="n in eventlist | filter:myFilter()" >
    <span>{{n.name}}</span>
    <span>{{n.date}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i'm sorry, that was wrong question. check my update.